# EJB java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, classloader

I'm using Eclipse with Glassfish for my first steps in Java EE. I've created three eclipse projects (JPA project, EJB project, Web project). I've created a local EJB bean TestBean with a local interface TestBeanLocal:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
class TestBean implements TestBeanLocal {
  @Override
  public void doSomething(List<JPAEntity> myEntities) {
    for(JPAEntity a : myEntities) {

    }
  }
}
```

and a ManagedBean that uses the EJB:

```
@MangagedBean
public class MyBean {
    @EJB
    private TestBeanLocal testBean;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
       //load JPAEntity from Database
       List<JPAEntity> myEntities = ....
       testBean.doSomething(myEntities);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I get a ClassCastException at the for loop in the TestBean.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: us.mypackage.jpa.JPAEntity cannot be cast to us.mypackage.jpa.JPAEntity
```

I found another stackoverflow question that says that this error message is because of two different classloaders. How can I fix this? Can I tell EJB to use the same classloader that my webproject uses?

Comment: Its been awhile since i used glassfish, but if you are deploying in the same ear, delegate the warclassloader to the earclassloader. Look at glassfish-web.xml and set delegate to true, so that the LocalBeanInterface get loaded by the same classloader

Comment: It happens because of some left overs from the old EntityManagerFactory, somehow its classloaders survived after redeployment, what you need to do is to close the factory just before you redeploy your app, you can use ServletContextListeners for that, it allows you to do exactly what you need, here is a turorial on how to implement it: http://4dev.tech/2015/08/example-of-servletcontextlistener-implementation/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the entity jar is located in both war and ear
Try to remove the entity jar from the war library
War should see the ear libraries file
HTH